# How do I setup MSVC "Native Tools Command Prompt" from .bat file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-c++

When Visual Studio 2019 is installed it installs a shortcut called:

```
x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019
```

that calls this .BAT file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
```

That contains:

```
@call "%~dp0vcvarsall.bat" x64 %*
```

Which I guess just passes "x64" as the first argument to vcvarsall.bat and forwards the rest of its arguments.  (I'm not sure what the "%~dp0" is or means).

vcvarsall.bat is much longer.

Anyway my question is: How do you write a .BAT file that sets up the environment that this shortcut does for the remainder of the .BAT file?

ie: I want to write a file called MyBuild.BAT that does:

1. sets up environment that vcvars64.bat does.
2. calls some build commands as if they were run from the "Native Tools Command Prompt" ?

On a unix-like system I might write something like:

```
source vcvars64.bat  (runs vcvars64.bat "inline" in caller environment)
run_my_build_commands
```

Comment: call "c:\jada\jada\vcvars64.bat"

Answer (score 3):

As per @HansPassant suggestion the solution I am using is:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
my_build_command %*
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark it as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.